# Adding a Button to toggle between graph and table using Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm creating charts with the Highcharts library and I wonder If I could add a button to toggle between the chart and the datatable . I am actually using this [Chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed).
Maybe someone could help me?

Comment: Do you mean draw both versions and then toggle which one to hide with CSS? Or dynamically change the content?

Comment: Yes, draw both versions as my table data is given as data for the high chart . I wanna toggle between datatable and highchart. I don't wanna change the content because data in my table is same as the chart.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/saipraneeth99/y1r7wLnq/15/ In this link, the way that toggle button works for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to toggle display style for chart and table container, for example:

```
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var chartContainer = chart.renderTo,
        dataTable = document.getElementById('datatable');

    if (chartContainer.style.display === "none") {
        chartContainer.style.display = "block";
        dataTable.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        chartContainer.style.display = "none";
        dataTable.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xnr1uckd/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.table